# Add dates in number format to forecasts

Tags: r, date, forecasting

I am doing a 12-steps ahead forecasting and I would like to add the date to each forecast (`cbind`) for an Excel table. I need to add 12 date points (they are in number, not in date format), to match the 12 predictions I computed.

The series looks like

```
2000, 2000.25, 2000.5, 2000.75, 2001, ... , 2016.75.
```

And I need

```
2017, 2017.25, ...., 2019.75.
```

I do not want to do it manually, because at some point I will update the database and have new observations and I don't want to do it all over again each time I rerun the code with updated database. How do you do that in R?

Comment: Have you tried `seq(2017, 2019.75, by=0.25)` ? You can check how this function works using ` ?seq`.

Comment: I know `seq`, of course! But next time I add data, the sequence will be 2017.25,...,2020. I need to account for the change in dates.

Comment: If you expect that to happen consistently you can just create the sequence `seq(2017, 2020, by=0.25)` and exclude the last element.

Comment: Luckily, `from` and `to` in `seq` do not have to be a specific number, but can be defined as a variable that depends on values of other variables. Thank you!